# Echo with parameters and without?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, echo

I know the following three statement will prodcue the same output:

```
echo "Hello" . "World! <br/>";
echo "Hello"; echo "World!", "<br/>";
echo "Hello", "World!", "<br/>";
```

But what is the preformance difference and why?

Is it slower to concatenate like `"String" . "String"` compared to `"String","String"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by performance... In terms of number of operations, your first example is best (has the least number of operations)... Your second and third examples are almost exactly the same.

Opcodes for the `echo "Hello" . "World! <br/>";` [HERE](http://3v4l.org/oYvSm/vld#tabs)

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Return found
filename:       /in/oYvSm
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  3
compiled vars:  none
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   CONCAT                                           ~0      'Hello', 'World%21+%3Cbr%2F%3E'
         1      ECHO                                                     ~0
   5     2    > RETURN                                                   1

branch: #  0; line:     3-    5; sop:     0; eop:     2
path #1: 0,
```

Opcodes for the `echo "Hello"; echo "World!", "<br/>";`[HERE](http://3v4l.org/nMufh/vld#tabs)

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Return found
filename:       /in/nMufh
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  none
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   ECHO                                                     'Hello'
         1      ECHO                                                     'World%21'
         2      ECHO                                                     '%3Cbr%2F%3E'
   5     3    > RETURN                                                   1

branch: #  0; line:     3-    5; sop:     0; eop:     3
path #1: 0,
```

Opcodes for the `echo "Hello", "World!", "<br/>";` [HERE](http://3v4l.org/LnPaY/vld#tabs)

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Return found
filename:       /in/LnPaY
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  none
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   ECHO                                                     'Hello'
         1      ECHO                                                     'World%21'
         2      ECHO                                                     '%3Cbr%2F%3E'
   4     3    > RETURN                                                   1

branch: #  0; line:     3-    4; sop:     0; eop:     3
path #1: 0,
```

So, you can clearly see that you are using one extra `echo` operation on the second and third examples. Performance (read speed) is nearly negligible in these examples though.

Answer (score 2):

The dot operator is the fastest.  You can test this by putting it in a loop and timing the output, as seen here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/high-performance-string-concatenation-in-php/

Comment: Also, using comma is inconsistent with the rest of PHP. So use dot operator for clarity too.

Answer (score 1):

Lines 2 and 3 are equivalent.

It will be slightly faster to use commas, because it isn't using concatenation.